# Sending one-time password by SMS directly to a phone number

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, one-time-password

I use AWS SES to send one-time passwords via email. I am implementing the same via SMS with AWS SNS.

I created a topic, `otp`, and manually added the phone number to it as a subscription.

The following code works both locally and on the server:

```
      var params = {
        // TODO: fix this.
        //PhoneNumber: "+351914...",
        TopicArn: "arn:aws:sns:...:...:otp",
        Message: "Your code is..."
      }
      var publish_text_promise = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31', profile_name: "sms"}).publish(params).promise();

      // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
      publish_text_promise.then(
        function(data) {
          console.log("Message sent: %o", params);
          console.log("MessageID is " + data.MessageId);
        }).catch(
          function(err) {
            console.error("Error in sending OTP by SMS");
            console.error(err, err.stack);
          });
```

I would like to send directly to the phone number, so it does not require manual intervention and I can add other users on the same topic. When I add `PhoneNumber` instead of `TopicArn`, it sometimes works, and sometimes I get this message:

```
InvalidParameter: Invalid parameter: PhoneNumber Reason: +351914... is not valid to publish to
```

The phone number is correctly formatted: when I tested it locally, it always worked.

I have the same code locally and remotely and the same AWS credentials file as well.

Why does the code work locally and sometimes fail remotely? How can I send directly to phone numbers?

Comment: guess you may need to include country code.

Comment: Your number should be be in proper E.1645 format which means +folllowedbycoutnrycodeanfthennumber probably your aremissing country code https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164

Comment: @Shiping I do have the phone number correctly formatted with the "+351" for Portugal. If the number were wrong, it would always fail.

Comment: If you try it via the Amazon SNS console, does it successfully send the message? Does it give the error immediately when calling `publish()`, or as a log entry? You might want to activate [Amazon SNS topic delivery logs for SMS messages](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/monitor-sns-texts-cloudwatch/).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It gives an error immediately in my code. I do have delivery logs; they show that all my deliveries in the last 2 months have succeeded. I will try the AWS SNS console this weekend so as not to confuse the user during their weekly usage at work.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I try on the SNS Console and get this empty error message: "An error occurred while trying to publish an SMS message to the selected target.
Error code: 401 - Error message:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was an invisible character in the phone number, which you can see after the 6:

```
InvalidParameter: Invalid parameter: PhoneNumber Reason: +3519...6‬ is not valid to publish to
```

I had cleaned the phone number before adding to Contacts on macOS, but it seems that Contacts adds these characters here and there. The character disappeared when I removed the phone number. Because the character was at the end, I missed it when I selected the phone number to copy-and-paste.

Following the comments, one solution to debug this issue is to try the AWS SNS console.

Therefore, this thread is closely related to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797980/aws-sns-invalid-parameter-phone-number-is-not-valid-to-publish-to-on-specif):

> This was definitely caused by an encoding issue, paste the code below into jsfiddle, and mouseover to see the warning on the first plus sign which reads:
>
> This character may get silently deleted by one or more browsers